# How can I open up a copy of a Contour analysis from within Workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-contour

I was wondering whether it is possible to have a button within Workshop that on click creates and opens a copy of an already existing contour analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You need to use the URL option of the button widget using the following pattern:
`https://STACK_URL/workspace/contour-app/overview/CONTOUR_ANALYSIS_TO_COPY_RID/copy`
[image: button widget set up]

You can get the RID of your contour analysis from the details sidebar:
[image: Where to find contour rid]